Master theorem's demonstration (CS) and O-big notation perplexities
i'm an undergraduate and i'm study the Master theorem which is used, usually, to determine a recursive algorithm's complexity. As i'm reading the demonstration, i'm stumbling upon certain points that leave me confused. Before proceding further i need to clarify certain things:

$n, a, b \in Z$
n is an array dimension, so it's always $n \geq 1$
this array gets divided in a number of sub-arrays with each length n/b
thus $a,b > 0$
you can assume that $\frac{n}{b^{i}}$ is always an integer
i is a sum's index and it goes from 0 to $log_{b}{n}$
$\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary
n is the variable that matters here, since we're trying to predict how long an algorithm takes given an input that has size n, everything else is therefore a parameter
O big, $\theta$ big, and $\Omega$ notation, in this context, were introduced in their weakened form. Not the one based on the limits, but the one based on inequalities

Now here is where what i'm confused about:

$T(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{log_{b}{n}}\theta(n^{log_{b}{a}}) = \theta(n^{log_{b}{a}}\cdot log_{b}n)$
$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{log_{b}{n}}O(n^{log_{b}({a}) -\epsilon}\cdot (b^{\epsilon})^{i}) = O(n^{log_{b}({a}) -\epsilon}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{log_{b}n}(b^{\epsilon})^{i})$

For the record, 1 and 2 appear in different proofs.
1 implies that i'm supposed to do: $\theta(n^{log_{b}{a}}) + \theta(n^{log_{b}{a}}) + ... + \theta(n^{log_{b}{a}})$ that then turns into $\theta(n^{log_{b}{a}}\cdot log_{b}n)$. But is this a legitimate property? As far as i know $\theta$ notation represents the combination of the O-big notation with the $\Omega$ big notation. But in the O-big notation: $O(f(n)) + O(f(n)) = O(f(n))$ and not $O(f(n)) + O(f(n)) = O(2\cdot f(n))$. Thus we would violate the O big notation's rules.
2 instead seems to make more sense, and it's just using the sum's properties and the O big notation's properties regarding the product of 2 O big. But i'm confused by the fact that the O big was brought out along with $n^{log_{b}{(a)}-\epsilon}{}$
